# How to update react state when using contextBridge/preload in electron app

Tags: reactjs, electron, ipcrenderer, ipcmain

I have an electron application that is using react. I am using the contextBridge in preload.js. I would like to pass a variable from app.js through the bridge to a function in the main process; which returns a value to the bridge and back to app.js where it will somehow update state and trigger a rerender. The following code is working up to the point of getting state to update. I do not understand how to get a variable from preload.js to app.js? My hopefully-temporary hack is to set localstorage from the preload and call a setTimeout function to watch for changes on specific variables. I know this is a less than interesting approach. Code is here:

app.js -

```
async function createSpreadsheet() {
  let x = await electron.google.createSpreadsheetFiles(sheetFileName)
}
```

preload.js -

```
const { ipcRenderer, contextBridge, net } = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electron', {
  google: {
    createSpreadsheetFiles(name) {
      ipcRenderer.send('gCreateSpreadSheetFile', name);
      let x = ipcRenderer.on('gCreateSpreadSheetFile-return', function (event, arg) {
      })
      return x
    },
  },
})
```

main.js -

```
  ipcMain.on('gCreateSpreadSheetFile', (event, name) => {
    async function all() {
      let resp = await g.createSheetFile(name, win)
      event.sender.send('gCreateSpreadSheetFile-return', resp)
    }
    all()
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ipcRenderer invoke and ipcMain handle:

`preload.js`

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electron', {
  google: {
    createSpreadsheetFiles: (name) => ipcRenderer.invoke('gCreateSpreadSheetFile-invoke', name),
  },
});
```

`main.js`

```
ipcMain.handle('gCreateSpreadSheetFile-invoke', (event, name) => {
  return 'value';
});
```

`renderer`

```
window.electron.google.createSpreadsheetFiles(spreadSheetName).then((value) => {
  console.log(value);
});
// or
var value = await window.electron.google.createSpreadsheetFiles(spreadSheetName);
```

On the documentation: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendererinvokechannel-args

Comment: OK I apologize for the premature acceptance. I have tried your code and I am still stuck with how to return from preload.js to app.js. I am sure it is a syntax issue, or I do not understand the return from preload. If you have time could you look at the code I wrote below. Thank you

Comment: Sorry I didn't test the code, I'll test it and see if I can fix it. I might have messed up because that method has worked well for me in the past.

Comment: Ok I finally am getting back to this. This syntax is working for me and I am marking your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I apologize for posting another question in the answer section, I do not understand how to format code in the comment response.

This code still will not return to app.js:

```
app.js    

const res = await electron.g.createSpreadsheetFiles(sheetFileName)
        console.log(res) // prints undefined, before code is excecuted
```

returns the res without waiting for a return from preload.js. Here is the code from preload.js

```
preload.js    

g: {
        createSpreadsheetFiles(name) {
          (async () => {
            const result = await ipcRenderer.invoke('gCreateSpreadSheetFile-invoke',  name);
            return result; 
          })();
      }
```

Comment: I've updated my answer to be clearer. By the way the preload.js file is redundant, using `createSpreadsheetFiles: (name) => ipcRenderer.invoke('gCreateSpreadSheetFile-invoke', name);` would have the same effect, and in app.js you should use `window.electron.g...`.